# encrypt key hexadecimal with another key same lenght

Tags: encryption

i need to encrypt an input of 16 bytes with a plain key of 16 bytes with 2 method of encryption CBC and ECB.
i have 2 files with :

1.txt : CB18D7B3101924314051647990A9C4E1

2.txt : 0000000000000000F05FBEFD564A164D

i need after encrypt the second key with the first key , to have a 3.txt file with result

like :

3.txt : D057E1DB9458102CFD06AFCA5504E598

thanks to help me with a program or command to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the question is how to encrypt the data *2* with the key *1* to obtain the encrypted data *3*. Further it looks like the encryption method is CAST, see:[CAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST-128).

Where:
1: `CB18D7B3101924314051647990A9C4E1`
2: `0000000000000000F05FBEFD564A164D`
3: `D057E1DB9458102CFD06AFCA5504E598`

The methods ECB and CBC can not both be used at the same time. See [Block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

Comment: thanks for reply  i don t need to use the 2 ecryption at same time , ineed just to get the result as 3 file

Comment: please i need help